# Issue with IModelValidatorProvider and IModelValidator implementations. The generated error is not treated correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-validation

I try to use `IModelValidatorProvider` and `IModelValidator` interfaces in my ASP.NET Core project for respective model validation.

Unfortunately it does not work as expected.
Namely my `ModelValidator` class (implements `IModelValidator`) returns only one error. As a result I see that `ModelState` contains one error with the expected text. It is fine.
`ModelState.ErrorsCount = 1`.
But the problem is new element is presented in `ModelState.Values`.
It has a key `Code.Code` instead of `Code` where `Code` is name of one of the model property. That is why the required text is not shown in validation field for `Code` property on page view.
The situation is different if I use `ModelState.AddModelError` method in the controller.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "something went wrong...");
```

`ModelState.Values` does not contain additional element with key `Code.Code`. It contains element with key `Code` (`ValidationState=Invalid`) and a error message is shown correctly.

I guess I am doing something wrong with model validators. But I am stuck and can't find the exact issue. Would be thankful for any advice.

Please find below the source code of my validators

```
public class CustomModelValidatorProvider : IModelValidatorProvider
{

    public CustomModelValidatorProvider()
    {
    }

    public void CreateValidators(ModelValidatorProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Results.Any(v => v.Validator.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomModelValidator)) == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType == typeof(DealRegistrationViewModel))
        {
            context.Results.Add(new ValidatorItem
            {
                Validator = new MyCustomModelValidator(),
                IsReusable = true
            });
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomModelValidator : IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var model = context.Container as DealRegistrationViewModel;

        if (context.ModelMetadata.ModelType == typeof(string) 
                && context.ModelMetadata.Name == nameof(model.Code))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code) == true)
            {
                return new List<ModelValidationResult>
                {
                    new ModelValidationResult(context.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, "Empty Code value is not accepted")
                };
            }
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

The validator is activated in `startup.cs` like this

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ModelValidatorProviders.Add(new CustomModelValidatorProvider());
});
```

Please find below with screenshot with `ModelState.Values` content in case of `ModelState.AddModelError` usage (works fine)

[image]

Please find below with screenshot with `ModelState.Values` content in case of Model validators usage (it does not work fine)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your code in your `MyCustomModelValidator`like below:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code) == true)
            {
                return new List<ModelValidationResult>
                {
                   new ModelValidationResult("", "Empty Code value is not accepted")
                };
                   
            }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: thank you, it works.

I was sure that empty string for MemberName parameter can be used to show summury validation messages.
How summary validation messages can be defined from the model validators in this case ?

Comment: In your code `context.ModelMetadata.Name == nameof(model.Code)`,You have already specified the property as code, so you don't need to specify the property name repeatedly in ModelValidationResult, which will cause duplication.

Comment: Thanks, Yinqiu. I have marked your answer as useful and accepted.

Comment: Glad to help you:)

Comment: the errors initiated by the respective ValidatorItem are available on the next page only. So when form button is pressed the validations based on view model fields attributes are fired and the respective error/validation messages are shown. Meanwhile model validations (IModelValidator.Validate) are called as well. But the respective error messages are not shown. These error messages available only on next page where form data are sent (posted). The question is how to make these errors (from IModelValidator) available on the initial page ? Right after the form button is pressed.